# Change cell value based off of selection from ListBox

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm currently trying to change a certain cells value based off of what is selected in a ListBox.

This is how I'm building my list box

```
Private Sub cmdAdd2_Click()
    Dim LR As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim i As Long
lstSelector.Clear
With ActiveSheet
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To LR
        If .Cells(r, 1).Value = Val(TextBox6.Value) And .Cells(r, 5).Value = "No" Then
            lstSelector.AddItem .Cells(r, 2).Value
            lstSelector.List(i, 1) = .Cells(r, 3).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
End With
```

This is working how I intended. The problem I am having is how the 5th column cell is being selected and edited.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
 Range("Trades").Cells(Me.lstSelector.ListIndex + 2, 5) = "Yes"
```

The above code works but only temperately and edits "random" row when the list box is refreshed. I'm guessing its an issue with this section of code.

What I want to happen is for Cell #5 for the row that is selected in the ListBox to change its value to "Yes" when cmdAdd_Click() is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second piece of code (`Range("Trades").Cells(Me.lstSelector.ListIndex + 2, 5) = "Yes"`) your are selecting ListIndex, that points to the position of an item in the list (first, second, third...), which has nothing to do with the row were data is in your worksheet.
Try with this:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd2_Click()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim i As Long
    lstSelector.Clear
    With ActiveSheet
        LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To LR
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value = Val(TextBox6.Value) And .Cells(r, 5).Value = "No" Then
                lstSelector.AddItem .Cells(r, 2).Value
                lstSelector.List(i, 1) = .Cells(r, 3).Value
                lstSelector.List(i, 2) = .Cells(r, 3).Row 'this line added for storing row number
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

and then

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim lItem As Long

    For lItem = 0 To lstSelector.ListCount - 1 'Scan all items in lstSelector
        If lstSelector.Selected(lItem) = True Then 'if selected...
           Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lstSelector.List(lItem, 2), 5) = "Yes" 'recall row number
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```